# Requisição Ajax usando Asp .net core

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estou com problemas nessa requisição... Está retornando 'nao foi' no console. O método getValue() está no Controller/HomeController.cs

/* JS */

```
 var obj = {
        emails: 'teste'
    }

    var json = JSON.stringify(obj)

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/getValue',
        data: json,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: (e) => {
            console.log('foi')
        },
        error: (e) => {
            console.log('nao foi')
        }
    })
```

/* getValue */

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult getValue(string dados) {
 
return View();
}
```

Também criei uma classe no Models>TesteModel.cs

```
public class TestModel {
   public string teste {get; set;}
}
```

Poderia me ajudar? Acho que o problema pode ser na url do ajax...
Mensagem de erro no console: POST https://localhost:44355/Home/getValue 500 jquery.min.js:2

Comment: Sua rota é `/Home` mesmo, com H maiúsculo?

Comment: Eu coloquei com H maiusculo, mas eu não sei se a url padrão pra acessar o HomeController é com H maiusculo.

Comment: @RennanAlves remova o `return View();` do seu método na `Controller`.  Você só pode retornar um View() que existe.

Answer (score 1):

Há vários problemas em seu código que não cabe abordar aqui, porém minha sugestão é que estude .NET Core e o padrão de arquitetura de software MVC (Model-View-Controller) e entenda como cada um deles funciona.

**Faça assim:**

---

### View (JS):

```
function getValue() {
    var obj = {
        "email": 'teste@TesteViewModel.com'
    }

    var data = JSON.stringify(obj);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/Home/GetValue',
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        success: (e) => {
            console.log('success')
        },
        error: (e) => {
            console.log('error')
        },
        complete: (e) => {
            console.log('complete');
        }
    });
}
```

---

### Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetValue([FromBody] TesteViewModel dados)
{
    var teste = new TesteViewModel
    {
        Email = dados.Email
    };

    return Json(teste);
}
```

---

### Model (ViewModel):

```
public class TesteViewModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

---